# Stream Foxnews/AbcNews swf video on iPhone's UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

I want to run a video from foxnews/abcnews in my news app. I have tried using UIWebView, SafariView and even launching it in safari, but it doesn't run. You can however run the url on your iphone safari browser easily (try copy pasting url from below). I have tried embedding the url in html and also using iframe.

**Here is my code**

```
let foxNewsUrl:String! = "https://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=4921342359001&d=video.foxnews.com&auto_play=true"
let abcNewsUrl:String! = "https://abcnewsplayer-a.akamaihd.net/player/2.19.0.0004/amp.premier/AkamaiPremierPlayer.swf?settings_url=https://abcnewsplayer-a.akamaihd.net/player/2.19.0.0004/amp.premier/amp.premier.flashonly.xml?sec=1&params=%7B%22playerId%22%3A%22facebookHTTPS%22%7D&data_feed_url=http://abcnews.go.com/video/itemfeed?id=39515399&auto_play=true&ad_control_enabled=false"

let embedHTML:String! = "<html><head></head><body style=\"margin:0\"> <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"\(foxNewsUrl)\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></embed></body></html>";

let nsurl = NSURL( string: abcnewHtml)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: nsurl!)

let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

// loadRequest in UIWebView:
myWebView.loadRequest(request)

// load embed html in UIWebView
myWebView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML!, baseURL: nil)
self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

// launch SafariViewController
let htmlUrl3 = NSURL( string: abcNewsUrl)
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: htmlUrl3!)
self.presentViewController(svc, animated: false, completion: nil)

// launch Safari outside of the app: this also doesn't work, 
// it opens a 'Safari cannot download this file' dialog.
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: foxNewsUrl!)!)
```

None of these are working. Please help. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific by "None of these are working"? Are you getting errors, crashes, or is nothing happening? Thanks.

Comment: No errors (I have 'AllowArbitraryLoads' turned ON'), no crashes. It is just blank. However, if I replace the url with any youtube url, it works fine.

Comment: `UIWebView` cannot load `.swf (flash)`. You can try `WKWebView` but I believe it too, cannot load `.swf`. You will have to get something to convert the flash file to mp4 or find a new URL that uses HTML5 or other media types.

Comment: @Brandon I tried with WKWebView too, the screen is not blank white like with UIWebView, but displays garbage as text as shown [here](http://imgur.com/LNTV7Sp) .
Can be conversion be done on the fly in the app itself, instead of using a third party server?